# &gt; added to images link in Wordpress

Tags: images

For some reason today my Wordpress decided to add > to every image link on the website, resulting 404 on every image.

Any idea how to resolve it?

Nothing has been changed from the last time it worked, not even a new plugin installed.

Comment: A new plugin could have updated which might be faulty. I would still go through and disable all plugins, add a new image (since the changes might be reverted when you disable plugins) to make sure that it is working.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an updated plugin incompatibility to me. Had similar issue, turned out to be a slideshow plugin.